# Turn of parallax for UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, ios7, parallax

In iOS 7 UIPopoverControllers have the parallax effect (foreground hovering over background).

This is especially ugly in a UISplitViewController that is in portrait mode.

- Lines are not on the same level. No matter how you hold it, initially the popover is 4-5 pixels above where it should be
- There are no separators (not even hairlines) on top / at the bottom of the popover. This results in the popover looking even more missplaced.

Has anyone found a good workaround/fix for this?

**Edit:**

[image: Screen of SplitViewController in Portrait mode]

**Edit 2:**

UIActionSheet also has this parallax effect.

**Edit 3:**

My delegate method that is somehow related to the presentation of the master

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Übersicht", nil);
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}
```

Comment: Is this a custom implementation of split view controller? I have not experienced this kind of behavior in our app.

Comment: Yes it is.. just make a new Master-Detail Application, deploy it on a real device and move it while in portrait. The master view will hover. Same goes for every other popover and action sheet. (But I embedded the split view in a container view to get a permanent nav bar, therefore you notice the hovering even more)

Comment: Normal popovers do, but not the split view one. It is created differently in Apple's UIKit implementation. Not sure why you have this. If you open Mail on your iPad, do you see the popover "wobble"?

Comment: Just try it out yourself. The default behavior for a master popover is to hover. If you look closely, you will notice that the delegate method takes an instance of UIPopoverController. You are right, the mail app does not have this effect. That is why I am asking how to turn it off.

Comment: It takes a `UIPopoverController`, but if you inspect the private properties of that popover, you will see difference between normal popovers. For instance, splitview popovers do not have a background view. Also, I do not see this behavior in our app, and it has a split view as well.

Comment: Then maybe you don't use the delegate methods to display? Anyway, I have this problem and it doesn't really help me that you don't.. this behavior is can be reproduced easily.. and I just hoped that there was a workaround for it (like *don't use delegate, display the master this way...*)

Comment: Please add the code you use to display in your question.

Comment: Repeat after me: *delegate*. I don't display the popover. But I will paste my delegate method, if that helps.

Comment: Good, constructive, attitude. That's exactly what I use in our app. Nothing of the sort you describe.

Comment: Could you please me how you solved this? I'm stuck at exactly the same problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using the split view delegate, I manually change the frame of the master in the willRotateToOrientation delegate. This works only if the master is a table view controller :(

Comment: Ok, thank you. This would be the last thing I'd do because I would have to change a lot of my controller's logics.

Comment: you don't... i wrote a super class for all my detail view controllers which they inherit from. pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little bit hacky, but works for `UISplitViewController`:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
{
    UIView *popoverView = [[aViewController.view superview] superview];
    popoverView.motionEffects = @[];
}
```

Comment: Seems much less hacky than my solution